# Error: too few arguments when I run the Python script

Tags: python

This is the first time i try to run a Python script.

I try to initiate the `pgeth.py` with the `genesis.json` from a prompt command.

I got this Error: `too few arguments`.

These are the commands on my windows prompt cmd line:

```
cd to/CreatePrivateEthereum-master_Folder
python pgeth.py -init

> pgeth.py: error: too few arguments
```

Content of `pgeth.py` script:

```
def init(args):
    """init command"""
    # account management
    initAccount()
    # init needed if there is no chaindata dir
    datadir = getDataDir()
    if checkDir(os.path.join(datadir, 'chaindata')):
        return
    geth = checkGethCommand()
    options = [ "--datadir", datadir, "--networkid", "100" ]
    # create the json genesis
    address = getAddress()
    txt = GENESIS.replace("$ADDRESS$", address)
    f = open("genesis.json", "w")
    f.write(txt)
    f.close()
    # launch the blockchain with the CustomGenesis.json file
    cmdInit = [ geth ] + options + [ "init", "genesis.json"]
    logging.debug("cmd: " + strCommand(cmdInit))
    subprocess.call(cmdInit)
```

Comment: Can you show us content of your `pgeth.py` script?

Comment: Please take a look,I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, by reading the [source code of pgeth.py](https://github.com/regispietra/CreatePrivateEthereum/blob/master/pgeth.py), the argument is called `init` not `-init`, run your script like this will not encounter any problem:

```
python pgeth.py init
```